# Flex 3.5a TileList - Is it possible to exclude specific items/indices?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, arraycollection, tilelist

I've got a Flex TileList which has an ArrayCollection as its data provider. The ArrayCollection is used elsewhere in the application so modifying the base data is not possible.

There are two items at the start of the collection (indices 0 and 1) which I don't want to be rendered.

Is it possible to exclude these items from the TileList rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you create a new collection using the same source as your original ARrayCollection.  Then apply a filter to remove those two items.  This will not affect the your original data source or the other ArrayCollection which contains all the data.

The alternate would be to extend the TileList to ignore the first two items in it's dataProvider.  I anticipate this would be difficult at best.

Comment: nice answer, @adamk you should definitely create a new ArrayCollection and just exclude the first 2.